# error trying to run project in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to run an **Angular2** project, but when i use `ng serve` command i have the following error:

See:

[image]

I installed `angular` 2 via `angular-cli` with the next steps:

```
 1. sudo npm install -g angular-cli
 2. sudo ng new mi-aplicacion
 3. cd mi-aplicacion (mi-aplicacion path)
 4. sudo ng serve
```

I already have install node.js

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings you need this

Answer (score 0):

Few gotchas here:

1. Make sure you are running your command prompt with admin privelages
2. Make sure you have updated version of node `node -v`
3. If the above 2 check out doing a `ng init` inside the folder helps it compile properly as per [Angular Cli github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/414)